# Set lockscreen image from source with different aspect ratio or small size

Tags: lock-screen

I have a habit of grabbing lock screen images from web, mostly web comics and their extra galleries. These images often are small, have wrong aspect ratio, or have parts such as speech bubbles, which I'd like to leave out.

I have not yet found a way to "zoom out" or just move the image so that image would cover only part of lock screen. Is this possible with the phone?

Only solution I have found is to put image to OneDrive, download to a PC, edit, save back to OneDrive, then access that from the phone. This is very tedious even when I am close to a computer I can use.

---

Here's an example of what I mean. Original is from a small public domain image, then there's a simulated result of setting it directly as lockscreen image in phone, and finally a demonstration of my current tedious method, a Paint-edited image of right size. It is not very important how the color outside original image is determined (with Paint it happens by selecting background color before enlarging canvas, or later with flood fill tool).

[image: Example of current vs desired effect]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about application recommendations "Can you suggest an app that does X?."

Comment: @row1 Removed any hint of apps... I think question still makes sense, so consider reopening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found a method to do this with one app. It's far from perfect, but at least it works.

- Find and install Fantasia Painter app.
- Load the image from gallery in the app.
- First you are in a view where you can enlarge or shrink canvas by dragging with finger from the corner markers. You can also rotate and move the image itself, often accidentally... It's a bit tricky to use, there's no undo. If you make a mistake, the easiest way to fix it I could find is: hit back and start over... Also, there's no way to get back to this view later that I could find, other than saving the image and loading it again from gallery.
- When you're happy with canvas size and image rotation, hit the green check-mark to proceed to actual painting view.
- Use the paint tool to fill any black area produced by enlarging canvas with roughly right color. *You can pick color from image by long touch.* I find the square brush with right settings (big, sharp, opaque) is best for this.
- Smudge tool with right settings works in some images to extend image to new canvas area. It's also a good way remove parts of image, or blend in areas first covered with paint tool.
- Experiment with different brush settings for all tools you use! They make a big difference, not just in the end result, but also in how accurate or how fast you can work.
- Watch carefully you don't mess up parts you don't want to, and just Undo right away when you do.
- Also check the other tools, but above are the ones I found most useful.
- Note that you can hide the tools and go full screen. Zooming and panning with two fingers works very nicely too, so just zoom in and out depending on if you're fixing a small detail or painting large area.
- Finally, save the image, go to gallery, set as lock screen! Perhaps delete any intermediate saves you may have done, while you're there.

Comment: PS. Not going to accept my own answer here, at least not for now. I hope there's a better tool or method for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Right now solution is only edit the picture with available picture edit apps in market and set as lock screen picture.

Comment: The thing is, I have not been able to find a picture edit app which actually can do this in a decent manner, strange as this sounds. Some collage creation tools seem to do *something* useful, but in the end turn out to be useless for lockscreen image creation.

Comment: What's your requirement? Crop, resize, rotate or something else? Hope you can find one from ([Windows Phone Photo Apps](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/top-free-apps/photo/photo))

Comment: Well, as it is said in the question, use an image as lockscreen so that it does not cover entire screen. For example, if I have a 640x400 image, I want to set it to be entirely displayed at the center of lockscreen, instead of having it zoomed and see only a vertical sliver of it. To do this by image editing, it requires making the canvas size bigger, adding pixels around the original image, trivial operation even with desktop Windows Paint.

Comment: Do you want set entire image as lock screen by fill free area with black or something?

Comment: Extra pixel fill method is not very important, anything sane is fine. Added an example image to the question.

Comment: Seriously it's an app suggestion, but I'm sorry that I can't find one apt for you.

Comment: Thanks anyway (and I wasn't expecting anybody to actively search for an app). It is a bit confounding really, that none of the many image edit apps I've tried have had a simple, plain "enlarge canvas" function.

Comment: FYI, in case you find it interesting I found an app which can do this, and wrote an answer about how to do it.

Comment: @hyde, That's good ;)